# Numpy array - TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python

I am new to python and got this error while trying to create a 2D array.

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array(([5,5,0,0][5,None,None,0][None,4,0,None][0,0,5,4][0,0,5,None]))
```

**Error Message**

```
TypeError: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: In the future, please explain a bit about what you are trying to do and make a shorter question title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing comma between elements and a square bracket `[]` or parentheses `()` that holds the elements of the array.

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array([[5,5,0,0], [5,None,None,0], [None,4,0,None], [0,0,5,4], [0,0,5,None]])
print(y)
```

**Output**

```
[[5 5 0 0]
 [5 None None 0]
 [None 4 0 None]
 [0 0 5 4]
 [0 0 5 None]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate the items in the array with commas.

```
y=np.array(([5,5,0,0], [5,None,None,0], [None,4,0,None], [0,0,5,4], [0,0,5,None]))
```

Comment: Got this error after this:ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted